# create-react-app SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs, create-react-app

NPM test works fine, it is only VSCode Jest extension which is not working and failing with this error.

I created the project using create-react-app and I don't want to eject. I am using TypeScript for the writing unit tests as well and it is failing.

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import React from 'react';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
```